# Which Steam friends have I played the most hours with?

Tags: steam

In Steam, is it possible to see how many hours in game I've played with each friend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't, using Steam Gauge allows you to check several steam statistics -as total played hours or how many multiplayer games you share with your friends, but not hours played in common.

You can check it here: https://www.mysteamgauge.com/